# Is "Jack was wearing a hat that it was too big for him" any different from "Jack was wearing a hat that was too big for him"?

Tags: relative-clauses

Do they mean the same, different, or is the first sentence wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is incorrect. *that* is already your subject in the subclause, so the *it* is completely unnecessary and even incorrect. If you split the sentence into two, you can leave out the *that* and use *it* instead.